# anonymous implementation causing memory leak

Tags: java, android, memory-management, memory-leaks, leakcanary

i m using leak canary to detect memory leak and i must say it is very good library to detect potential memory leak below is the leak report produce by it.i am not able to find how to remove this anonymous implementation.

GoProFragment has leaked:

> - GC ROOT java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.
> - references MainActivity$5.this$0 (anonymous subclass of java.util.TimerTask)
> - references MainActivity.mHelper
> - references IabHelper.mPurchaseListener
> - references GoProFragment$2.this$0 (anonymous implementation of IabHelper$OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener)
> - GoProFragment instance

```
**GoProFragment.java**
public class GoProFragment extends BaseFragment {

    @Bind(R.id.btn_subscription_yearly)
    Button btnsubScriptionYearly;
    @Bind(R.id.btn_subscription_monthly)
    Button monthly;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    String product_price_one, product_price_two, product_price_three;
    @Bind(R.id.subscription_type)
    TextView subScriptionType;
    @Bind(R.id.graph_paid_feature)
    ImageView imageView;
    Bitmap icon;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pro_layout, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        activity.preferences.setDisplayUpgrade(false);
        icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(activity.getResources(), R.drawable.subscription_img_two);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(icon);
        subScriptionType.setText(activity.preferences.getSubscriptionType());
        String[] sku = { Util.SKU_CHALLENGE,  Util.SKU_SUBSCRIPTION,  Util.SKU_YEAR_SUBSCRIPTION};
        if(isNetworkAvailable(activity)) {
            activity.mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(true, Arrays.asList(sku), mGotInventoryListener);
            showProgressDialog();
        }
        if (activity.preferences.isHasSubscription()) {
            /*btnsubScriptionYearly.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            monthly.setVisibility(View.GONE);*/
        }
        return view;
    }
    IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mGotInventoryListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory) {
            dismissProgressDialog();
            product_price_one = inventory.getSkuDetails( Util.SKU_SUBSCRIPTION).getPrice();
            product_price_two = inventory.getSkuDetails( Util.SKU_YEAR_SUBSCRIPTION).getPrice();
            product_price_three = inventory.getSkuDetails( Util.SKU_CHALLENGE).getPrice();
            monthly.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            btnsubScriptionYearly.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            monthly.setText(activity.getString(R.string.monthly_subscription_text, product_price_one));
            btnsubScriptionYearly.setText(activity.getString(R.string.yearly_subscription_text, product_price_two));

        }

    };

    @OnClick(R.id.btn_subscription_monthly)
    public void onSubscription() {
        if (Validator.isNotNull(activity.mHelper)) {
            if (!activity.mHelper.subscriptionsSupported()) {
                 Util.showToast(activity, getString(R.string.subscription_not_supported));
                return;
            }
            if (!activity.mHelper.getAsyncInProgress()) {
                activity.mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(activity,
                         Util.SKU_SUBSCRIPTION, IabHelper.ITEM_TYPE_SUBS,
                         Util.RC_REQUEST, mPurchaseFinishedListener,  Util.PAYLOAD);
            }
        }
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.btn_subscription_yearly)
    public void onYearSubscription() {
        if (Validator.isNotNull(activity.mHelper)) {
            if (!activity.mHelper.subscriptionsSupported()) {
                 Util.showToast(activity, getString(R.string.subscription_not_supported));
                return;
            }
            if (!activity.mHelper.getAsyncInProgress()) {
                activity.mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(activity,
                         Util.SKU_YEAR_SUBSCRIPTION, IabHelper.ITEM_TYPE_SUBS,
                         Util.RC_REQUEST, mPurchaseFinishedListener,  Util.PAYLOAD);
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
        final ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (connectivity != null) {
            NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
            if (info != null)
                for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
                    if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                        return true;
                    }
        }

        return false;
    }
    IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
        public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase purchase) {

            // if we were disposed of in the meantime, quit.
            if (activity.mHelper == null) {
                return;
            }

            if (result.isFailure()) {
                return;
            }
            if (! Util.verifyDeveloperPayload(purchase)) {
                return;
            }
            if (purchase.getSku().equals( Util.SKU_SUBSCRIPTION)) {
                // bought the infinite gas subscription
                setPremium(purchase, Calendar.MONTH);
            } else if (purchase.getSku().equals( Util.SKU_YEAR_SUBSCRIPTION)) {
                // bought the infinite gas subscription
                setPremium(purchase, Calendar.YEAR);
            }
        }
    };
    public void setPremium(Purchase purchase, int duration) {
        if ( Util.verifyDeveloperPayload(purchase)) {
            activity.preferences.setHasSubscription(true);
            if (Validator.isNotNull(activity.adView)) {
                activity.adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
             Util.showToast(activity, getString(R.string.upgraded_successfully));
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTime(new Date(purchase.getPurchaseTime()));
            calendar.add(duration, 1);
            activity.preferences.getUserInfo().setSubscriptionEndOn(calendar.getTime());
            if(purchase.getSku().equals( Util.SKU_SUBSCRIPTION))
            {
                activity.preferences.setSubscriptionType(activity.getResources().getString(R.string.monthly));
            }
            else {
                activity.preferences.setSubscriptionType(activity.getResources().getString(R.string.yearly));
            }
            activity.preferences.getUserInfo().setPremium(true);
            //subscriptionEndOn.setText(dateFormat.format(activity.preferences.getUserInfo().getSubscriptionEndOn()));
        }
    }

    private void showProgressDialog() {
        if (!activity.isFinishing() && progressDialog == null) {
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity,R.style.CustomProgressDialog);
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            progressDialog.show();

        }

    }

    /**
     * dismiss Progress Dialog.
     */
    private void dismissProgressDialog() {
        if (!activity.isFinishing() && progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            progressDialog=null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        if(Validator.isNotNull(icon)){
            icon.recycle();
        }
        super.onDetach();
    }
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: @ bub how to fix this leak

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is a problem. You can hold onto state in a Fragment but you should call `setRetainInstance(true);` in the `onCreate` callback.

See [this article](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html)

Alternatively you could set the field `mGotInventoryListener = null;` in the `onDetach` callback.

Comment: @ Adriaan Koster i tried it but still it giving leak